# why GA 4 user is different for event cont. As i checked we have 7 user but event count is 28

Tags: google-ads-api, google-analytics-4, google-ads-script

I have faced some issues between GA4 user and event count. As i have checked yesterday data, we received 7 users throgh ads but count was 28. Which thing is wrong i don't know.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtaFy.png)

please help me regarding this so i will setup the correct conversion tracking.